# Have two of the same nodes on the screen at once Swift SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a space shooter game. I have created an enemy node. What I want to do is have 4 of those nodes in each corner of the screen. In other words, I want to spawn multiple copies of the same node at the same time. When the game loads, I want there to be four nodes, that are all the same. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Create four nodes, just like you created one node.  If you have a custom SpriteKit subclass (let's say of the SKSpriteNode), then you would create four of them, and add them to your scene normally.

Comment: @Gliderman so I need to create four duplicate nodes?

Comment: Yes, and it would be easier to have a custom subclass so that you do not clutter your main game code.

Comment: You won't have 4 copies of the same node, you'll have 4 nodes that look the same (same SKTexture) and behave the same. Don't try to create a node and then copy it.

Comment: @SteveIves how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a section of code I use to generate a row of 4 space invaders. I reuse the same SKSpriteNode() variable as once the node has been added to the scene, the variable is no longer required:

```
    for invaderPosition in 100.stride(to: 500, by: 120) {
        invader = SKSpriteNode(texture: texturesA[0])
        invader.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(invaderPosition), y: 200)
        invader.xScale = 8
        invader.yScale = 6
        invader.color = SKColor.redColor()
        invader.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
        invader.name = "InvaderA"
        invader.texture = texturesA[1]
          invader.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(texturesA, timePerFrame: self.timePerMove)))
        addChild(invader)
    }
```

invader is defined as an SKSpriteNode property. `texturesA` is just an array of `SKTextures`; timePerMove is just a time interval after which the invader should move (in `Update`) and change shape(texture).

```
var invader = SKSpriteNode()
var texturesA:[SKTexture] = []
let timePerMove: CFTimeInterval = 1.0
```

So you could do something similar except the invader's positions would be the 4 corners rather than a row.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the copy command,

```
let newNode = originalNode.copy() as! SKSpriteNode;
```

Comment: Will this also copy all of the code associated with that node?

Comment: code? No code does not exist at runtime as far as the app is concerned,  whatever variables inside of your object will be copied over, with a few exceptions, I believe children nodes and physics bodies do not get copied over,  so you will need to extend the copy functionality for those